# Android cursor loader load sqlite by page?

Tags: android, pagination, android-cursorloader

There's amount of data in sqlite db, and my activity needs to use ContentProvider(db data  access api), CursorLoader(controlled by LoaderManager ),  and SimpleCursorAdapter to show the cursor data from loader and delivery them to ListView(through override bindView method).

For a better UI experience, I want to load a page size data once time through CursorLoader, and when the listview scroll to the bottom, click "load more" to call CursorLoader to continue loading the next page data, but the previous data also must be shown in listview, just like view twitter or facebook timeline.

My question is that, if I change cursorloader uri(update "limit" and "offset" parameters) and restart loader to load next page, the simpleCursorLoader will only show the newest cursor(that is newest page data) but lose the previous. How should I design the loading mechanism to make the process more like facebook timeline?

Comment: Wall of text here. Please add some relevant code: what have you tried and what is the problem with it.